# Rails - first_or_create adding duplicate records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have some seeds in my rails app that I am trying to get to grips with. I'll start with the code in question:

```
make = Make.where(value: 'Alfa Romeo').first_or_create
model = make.models.where(value: '147').first_or_create
trim = model.trims.where(value: '1.6 TS 3d (2001 - 2005)').first_or_create
values = [
 {value: '2001 (X)'},
 {value: '2001 (Y)'},
 {value: '2001 (51)'},
 {value: '2002 (51)'},
 {value: '2002 (02)'},
 {value: '2002 (52)'},
 {value: '2003 (52)'},
 {value: '2003 (03)'},
 {value: '2003 (53)'},
 {value: '2004 (53)'},
 {value: '2004 (04)'},
 {value: '2004 (54)'},
 {value: '2005 (54)'},
 {value: '2005 (05)'}
]
values.each do |item|
  trim.model_years.where(item).first_or_create
end
```

What I am expecting from this code is for it to create or locate the make, model and trim, and then associate the appropriate model years with the trim.

What is happening, however, is that duplicate model years are being created - instead of associating the trim with '2001 (X)', for example, it is creating a new record with the value '2001 (X)' - to be clear, it is behaving as though I am using create, not first_or_create.

Can anyone suggest why this is happening and help me to rectify it?

EDIT: To avoid confusion, I have adjusted the code above to reflect my current code, without the find_or_create_by issues referenced in the first answer. The code above is still creating duplicates.

EDIT 2: It has occurred to me that I might be fundamentally be going wrong with my code - what I am trying to do is create an association between the trim and the model_year (which is set up as a many-to-many relationship). As such, perhaps where I am going wrong is that I am creating records, when really I just want to find an existing record and add an association.

As such, I should be using a statement that declares an association without creating a new object, not first_or_create.

I have thus amended my statement to the following, which is working:

```
trim.model_years << ModelYear.where(item).first_or_create
```

Thanks for your assistance everyone!

Comment: It might be useful to note that I am not getting any duplicates on Make, Model or Trim; the only duplicates are the Model_years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some corrections here :

```
make = Make.find_or_create_by_value('Alfa Romeo')
model = make.models.find_or_create_by_value('147')
trim = model.trims.find_or_create_by_value('2.0 Lusso 5d (2001 - 2005)')
values = [
 {value: '2001 (X)'},
 {value: '2001 (Y)'},
 {value: '2001 (51)'},
 {value: '2002 (51)'},
 {value: '2002 (02)'},
 {value: '2002 (52)'},
 {value: '2003 (52)'},
 {value: '2003 (03)'},
 {value: '2003 (53)'},
 {value: '2004 (53)'},
 {value: '2004 (04)'},
 {value: '2004 (54)'},
 {value: '2005 (54)'},
 {value: '2005 (05)'}
]
values.each do |item|
  trim.model_years.where(item).first_or_create
end
```

If you use `_by_value`, ActiveRecord expects a ... value! Not a hash :)

Comment: Thanks for the update - though interestingly the problem is with the model_years values (created by the loop at the bottom that uses first_or_create)... could the other issues have had a knock-on effect?

Comment: Well if you were creating a new trim each time instead of finding it, then you'd recreate all the model_years since it was a different trim. Did you try again? Still makes dupplicates?

Comment: Yes, just tried it again and I am still getting duplicates. I have updated the code in my question to my new code, which avoids using any find_or_create_by statements, to avoid confusion.

Comment: Weird, try this maybe instead ? `ModelYear.where(item.merge({trim_id: trim.id }))`. Also try to log  the tirm id each time so you double check that it's not because you have duplicate trims

Comment: It has occurred to me that the overall approach with this code may be wrong; it is essentially looking for model years that exist already on the trim, and since there are none it is always adding a new model_year, not just an association to an existing model year with the same value.

Comment: Yeah well, the second time you execute this code, since you're working on a static value to get the trim, you shouldn't insert duplicates for this particular trim.